# Switching between UIViewControllers within UINavigationController

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

So I'm stuck with a little problem that seems simple but is giving me fits.

Basically, I've got this kind of thing set up:

(1)-->(2)-->(3)

I drill down into a table, and once I'm at (3), I'd like to be able to swipe between two different views, while keeping the hierarchy intact. Like this:

(1)-->(2)-->(3a)/(3b) where 3a and 3b are able to be swiped back and forth. I also want to keep the back arrow for (2) on both views so that a user can go back.

The problem I'm having is that 3a and 3b will need to do separate calls for JSON data, so it's more than just loading two images. I really need to load each entirely...

Any idea where to start? I'm experienced, but this just seems totally confusing. And I'm N2Deep to use storyboards now. Many thanks for any help!

The usual way I'd push a new view is like what I've done below. This obviously doesn't work in this case...

```
if (!self.objTomorrowDetailViewController) { self.objTomorrowDetailViewController = [[TomorrowDetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"TomorrowDetailViewController" bundle:nil]; } 
[self.navigationController pushViewController:self.objTomorrowDetailViewController animated:YES];
```

Comment: maybe you can use a UIPageViewController with 2 pages for (3)

Comment: 3a and 3b are view controllers or just views?

Comment: Thanks--haven't investigated UIPageViewControlller for this. Checking it out now. Not sure if that totally solves the problem of keeping the Navigation trail and swapping between the two other views (3a and 3b).

Moxy, 3a and 3b are UIViewControllers.

Comment: If this helps, it's almost like I'd like to have a tabbed thing going within the navigation chain. Except instead of tabs, I would like it to be done with swipes.

Comment: Could you just use a pagin UIScrollView with only horizontal scrolling allowed. Then you just have the UIScrollView in (3) and add the two views as subviews, with view B set at x = scrollview.frame.size.width, and then have the scrollview content size as twice it's width.

Comment: I considered that, but as I'm doing two different JSON calls (one for each of these views), I'd prefer to do that only if the user swipes. I'm using the Loading HUD, so I'm cool with that happening on each swipe. I really just want to do a simple load like I would on the navigation controllers above. Argh. Maybe a tab bar is the way to go?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `navigationController.viewControllers` to get the current view stack, create a new one based on it (either via a mutable, or the new syntax `@[oldVCs[0],oldVCs[1],newVC]`). Set that to be the new stack with `[navigationController setViewControllers:newVCArray animated:YES]`.

Comment: Hi Kevin, Many thanks!! So here's my issue. I kind of get what you're saying, but not able to totally get it. My code is like this, once I've detected the swipe: if (!self.objTomorrowDetailViewController) {
            self.objTomorrowDetailViewController = [[TomorrowDetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"TomorrowDetailViewController" bundle:nil];
        }
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:self.objTomorrowDetailViewController animated:YES];

Comment: This crashes, of course. How can I repurpose what you did into my code. Again, a million thanks.

Comment: You should edit the code you have into your original question. And if you're swiping, you probably would be better off with a `UIPageControl` or a `UIPageViewController`.

Comment: Could you elaborate? That's the problem I'm having--editing the code into my original question...thanks again

Comment: Right under the tags you should see "share | edit | flag" or something similar.  Click on "edit." Indent the code four spaces to put it in a code block, and indent properly beyond that. And there should be more editing help on the right side.

Comment: Thanks again, Kevin. Working on it now.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to do this is with a custom container controller as your controller 3. When you do your push from 2, it would load the custom container which you could have set to display one of two (or more if you wanted) of its child controllers.  The swipe gesture would switch between the container controller's 2 child controllers, and you could still get back to 2 from either view.

Comment: Appreciate it @rdelmar. Been looking into that since your post. Will report back in an effort to help anyone else out who's run into this issue. Thanks again!